# OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe with Django-pipeline

Tags: django, python-2.6, django-pipeline

I have recently installed django-pipeline on CentOS 5.7. I have yuglify installed at /usr/local/bin/yuglify and have changed PIPELINE_YUGLIFY_BINARY to point there.

However whenever I run collectstatic I get the following:

```
OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Any help will be really appreciated.(Using Django 1.5.1 and python 2.6.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to symlink the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/node --> /usr/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/yuglify --> /usr/bin/yuglify
```